# How to use timeline when playing videos using javafx

Tags: javafx-2

We are using JavaFx MediaPlayer to play the .mp4 formates
i've the problem with time line, my issue is if we click on any point on time line,
it should play from that point. For that i've used the below code

```
timeSlider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(timeSlider.getValue()));
       }
    });
```

but this is not working properly. can any one help me to resolve the above issue please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial from Oracle about [creating a Video Player Control for JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm).

You can see the tutorial player in action in the [JavaFX Ensemble](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Media/Advanced%20Media) application.

The tutorial includes information on incorporating a player timeline.

Here is a screenshot of the JavaFX Video Player Control with Timeline from Ensemble.

[image: javafxmediaplayer]

The steps to create a slider to control the [MediaView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) position are:

1. Create the `MediaView` and it's associated `MediaPlayer`.
2. Create a `Slider` to control the time.
3. Listen for changes to the `Slider` and update the `MediaPlayer` position as appropriate.
4. Listen for change to the `MediaPlayer` current time and update the `Slider` as appropriate.

Some time slider specific code snippets from the sample are:

```
// Media player
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));

// Time label
Label timeLabel = new Label("Time: ");
timeLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
mediaBar.getChildren().add(timeLabel);

// Time slider
timeSlider = new Slider();
HBox.setHgrow(timeSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
timeSlider.setMinWidth(50);
timeSlider.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
    public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
        if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
            // multiply duration by percentage calculated by slider position
            if(duration!=null) {
                mp.seek(duration.multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / 100.0));
            }
            updateValues();
       }
    }
});
....
protected void updateValues() {
    if (playTime != null && timeSlider != null && volumeSlider != null && duration != null) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Duration currentTime = mp.getCurrentTime();
                playTime.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                timeSlider.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                if (!timeSlider.isDisabled() && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) && !timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                    timeSlider.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis() * 100.0);
                }
                if (!volumeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                    volumeSlider.setValue((int) Math.round(mp.getVolume() * 100));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
...
mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
    @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
            updateValues();
    }
});
// and also invoke updateValues when the MediaPlayer is played, paused, etc.
```

Comment: Hi Jewelsea thanks for giving the reply.I am not success with the solution you provided here.I think i have not mentioned my problem clearly.I have edited my original question.Can you plz have a look into it.Once again Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 0):

Inside listener on slider value invalidation you should check if user pressed mouse button recently (for example, within last 100 ms). Example code in Scala (rather simple to translate to Java):

```
val timeSlider = new Slider {
  /**
   * @return true, if user was pressed mouse button within last `t` ms
   */
  def mouseWasPressedWithinLast(t: Long): Boolean =
    (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeMousePressed) <= t

  private var lastTimeMousePressed = 0l

  addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (e: MouseEvent) => {
    lastTimeMousePressed = System.currentTimeMillis()
  })
}

timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
  def invalidated(ov: Observable) {
    // Position should be updated in one of the two cases:
    //   1. if user is sliding (then isValueChanging == true), or
    //   2. if user clicked on slider to set it to new position (has recently pressed mouse button).
    if (timeSlider.isValueChanging || timeSlider.mouseWasPressedWithinLast(100)) {
      updatePosition(timeSlider.getValue)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the original question and to expand on Nikolay's point:

Using Oracle's original code from "http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/media-player.htm" found in the source code MediaPlayer.zip the code suffers from the following problems.  When the user clicks on the button/knob widgets within the slider or on the bar area outside of the knob the value changes appropriately.  However, when the media is playing the user can only adjust the play time position or volume by moving the knob only.  The slider also moves sluggishly via the knob widget when the video is playing.

The fix problem is alleviated by Nikolay's suggestion.  This suggestion should be added to both sliders.  If you change both sliders to this YieldingSlider below you will see more responsive slider reaction even when video is playing and when the slider widgets are adjusted by either clicking on the bar or the knob of the sliders.

```
class YieldingSlider extends Slider
{
    private long lastTimeMousePressed = 0;

    public YieldingSlider()
    {
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(final MouseEvent event)
            {
                lastTimeMousePressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean mouseWasPressedWithinLast(long t)
    {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeMousePressed) <= t;
    }
}
```